# Способ вырезать лицо (и только лицо!) из изображения

Tags: python

Добрый день, каким способом возможно реализовать данную задачу? Определить лицо я смогу с помощью библиотеки dlib на Python; получаю прямоугольную область, но как организовать поиск так, чтобы "ненужные" мне пиксели сделать прозрачным? Dlib выделяет либо прямоугольную часть, либо создает 68 точек на лице.

Comment: Есть образец картинки и наглядное отображение найденных точек? Если точки в самом лице - то можно пройтись по самым крайним и интерполяцией сделать нечто более менее среднее, не знаю что получится... Если точки расположены по периметру лица... то тут даже делать нечего, опять же, интерполяция для сглаживания и всё готово.

Comment: Образец: https://pp.userapi.com/c840633/v840633810/1c8b8/s6wA36NYQhg.jpg
Координаты точек известны

Answer (score 0):

1. Пройдитесь по всем точкам и оставьте только те которые дальше всего от центра и проведите между ними линию по окружности.
2. Определите цвет этого многоугольника как прозрачный(`cv2`, `PIL`...)

Вопросы?